# LXQt works perfectly on a fresh Arch install then only get a black screen after rebooting

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xinit, lxqt

LXQt works perfectly after a fresh Arch install on my laptop, then I reboot, and without changing anything, simply logging in as the same user from before, running startx like before, instead of lxqt like before I get a dead black screen. No signs of life.

This happened twice on two fresh Arch installs in the last 24 hours. Following the docs to a tee I thought.

I've tried removing the .Xauthority file as suggested in other posts to no avail and toggling through the tty screens to no avail (it defaults to the screen I run startx in), is there anything else I can try?

It seems like there must be some setting or config that is getting lost or created during the reboot process that is causing the break right? There is no xorg.conf file being created as mentioned in another post. And my ~/.xinitrc file is the same before and after the reboot. I'm stumped.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks heaps!

EDIT:

~/.xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

exec startlxqt
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log (filtered to errors and warnings as too big to include all - full version at https://justpaste.it/1dqn7)

```
[    59.429] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.5
Release Date: 2017-10-12
[    59.429] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    59.429] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.54-1-lts x86_64 
[    59.429] Current Operating System: Linux h 4.13.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 8 11:54:06 CET 2017 x86_64
[    59.429] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=45b53c70-775d-42ed-acc7-c392bc87c007 rw quiet
[    59.430] Build Date: 12 October 2017  09:59:53PM
[    59.430]  
[    59.430] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    59.430]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    59.430] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    59.549] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[    59.549]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.549] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[    59.549]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.549]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[    59.550] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[    59.550]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.562] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    60.434] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    60.471] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[    60.471] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    60.471] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    60.471] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.471] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    60.471] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    60.471] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    60.471] (II) Unloading nv
[    60.471] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.495] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    60.495] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[    60.495] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    60.495] (II) Unloading intel
[    60.495] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.495] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.495] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    60.495] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.496] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    60.496] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.496] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    60.496] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    60.496] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    60.496] (II) Unloading vesa
[    60.496] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.496] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  387.22  Wed Oct 25 22:14:47 PDT 2017
[    60.496] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    60.585] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    60.585] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    61.073] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[    62.239] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
```

Comment: If you run `startx` there *will* be an xorg.log. Arch doesn't create an xorg.conf (and you don't likely need one anyway). Please add the log and your `.xinitrc` to your question.

Comment: Xorg log is to big to include if the question body, can I attach as a file or send it to you somehow?

Comment: Upload it to a paste site and link to it.

Comment: Great idea thanks - https://justpaste.it/1dqn7

Comment: This is a hybrid graphics machine? Have you configure bumblebee/optimus?

Comment: No I haven't but will definitely try, thanks so much for all of your help! P.s. any idea as to why it worked the first time and not on reboot?